# Sound Problem after updating Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10

Tags: upgrade, sound, 13.04

After going through various forums and applying those methods, my problem still persists.
I had completely removed pulseaudio as well as alsameter and then re-installed them followed by a force reload and a restart.
Sound is still not coming. Please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now!
I just needed to select the correct "Play Sound through" option in Settings->Sound.
It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Which model computer do you have? If you have HP you can install [this package](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&softwareitem=PSG_I23778-109040).